# What is the best way to automatically include transitive dependencies in classpath for a Maven project?

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml, classpath

Transitive dependencies are not found during runtime

I Have a project which has a dependency like this

- Dependency A

  - dependency A.1

maven install runs successfully, but when the spring application runs, dependency A.1 is not found, I am seeing classdefnotfoundexception for it.

How to add all the transitive dependencies to the classpath without explicitly bringing them into my pom.xml?
There are many dependencies in Dependency A and it might lead to human errors if I add them one by one.

Comment: Transitive dependencies are added automatically.

Comment: Would you mind posting the exact exception. classdefnotfoundexception doesn't sound like it. In case you're generating a war, is dependencyA.1 inside the WEB-INF\lib folder of your war?